# How to check if an executable is a Console or GUI App?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

Apologies in advance if this question isn't the most understandable, I'm still very new to C# and Windows Forms.

I'm making a program that allows the user to run multiple Console App programs (in my case, Discord bots) in one organized place. I'm working on the "Open File" dialog right now, and I was wondering if there was a way to determine if the .exe file chosen was a console app? If this check isn't in place, my program would crash if the user chose an .exe file that isn't a console app.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: This feels like quite an advanced project for someone “very new to C#”, but good on you for giving it a go anyway. One question though, why would your program crash if loading something that isn’t a console app?

Comment: @brads3290 I thought it might crash because I want it to output everything from the console to a richTextBox so the user can see what the console app is doing. My concern was if the selected program wasn't a console app, then something would throw an exception or the program would just crash.

Comment: It shouldn’t crash. But you can always handle the exception in the case that it throws.

Comment: FYI, both the answers you have were generated by ChatGPT. See my comments on both. I think I have an answer for you but I can’t test it right now. I’ll get it working tomorrow and post it for you.

Comment: I figured they were generated by AI, haha. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why would your program crash?

Comment: There's a Win32 API, [GetImageConfigInformation()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-getimageunusedheaderbytes) (also its counterpart, `GetImageUnusedHeaderBytes`) that can be used to inspect the image file of a PE. Among the information retrieved, the [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32) struct `Subsystem` member specifies what type of sub-system is required to run the image (e.g, CUI, character mode or GUI, graphic interface)

Comment: @Jimi This is looking like something for C++, not C#? Is there a way to do this in C# or will I have to use C++?

Comment: @shingo Bad choice of words on my part. The program probably wouldn't crash but it definitely wouldn't behave as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Targeting .NET Core or .NET 5+, you can make use of the `System.Reflection.PortableExecutable` namespace, part of the  `System.Reflection.Metadata` assembly.

Its [PEReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable.pereader) class (not available in .NET Framework) allows to read the [PE Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable.peheader) without the need to PInvoke, e.g., [ImageLoad()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-imageload) or [MapAndLoad()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-mapandload) etc.

It's quite simple to use.
Initialize a `PEReader` class using a Stream you have opened using, e.g., `File.Open()` or initializing a `FileStream`, passing the **full path** of an image file, then read the content of the [PEHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable.peheaders) object you get back.

A minimal implementation (.NET 5+, C# 8.0+):

```
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

string imagePath = @"[Full path of executable file]"
bool isConsoleApp = GetExeType(imagePath, out bool isDll) == Subsystem.WindowsCui;

// [...]

public Subsystem GetExeType(string imagePath, out bool isDll) {
    using var stream = File.Open(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    using var reader = new PEReader(stream);
    isDll = reader.PEHeaders.IsDll;
    return reader?.PEHeaders?.PEHeader != null ? reader.PEHeaders.PEHeader.Subsystem : Subsystem.Unknown;
}
```

Of course you could return a `PEHeader` class object and inspect all the other properties available. You, mostly, have what you would get from a [LOADED_IMAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/ns-dbghelp-loaded_image) struct